# setting default values for a multiselect parameter in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with a parameter which allows multiple selecttions. Now what ssrs has done is that it has added a "select all " option in the parameter drop down. What I need is that if the user does not select anything all should be selected. That is I want all as default value. Please help.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using SSRS 2008, you have a couple of options.  If your parameter is populated from a dataset/query, then you should be able to choose Get Values From A Query in the Default Values tab of the Parameter.  If you select the dataset that your lookup is being populated from, and the ID column, all values will be selected when you run the report.

If your parameter is populated via a list you have entered, then choose Specify Values in Parameter Properties and Add all the Labels/Values in your list.

I'm not sure if this is the same for SSRS 2005.